I am a man who wants to self study psychology I
I want a circiculum to self study the subject

Welcome mohamed. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] particularly the [ask] section. Please note that we're a strict question and answer site and - you've not asked a question. Remember to show your own prior researches into the topic as you edit.
